# Lost access to HTTP Request after upgrade to .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: asp.net, wcf, .net-4.5, asp.net-4.5

I have a WCF service that accepts a POST request from jqGrid in the form of HTML form and returns JSON.

While things were on .NET 4.0, all worked fine. I could access form fields inside the service via `request["fieldName"]`. Once I upgraded to .NET 4.5, all my `request["fieldName"]` are now blank.  Is there some kind of known issue with .NET 4.5, WCF and `HttpContext.Current.Request`?

Here is an example:

```
 POST http://{REMOVED}/Grid.svc/Execute HTTP/1.1
 Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
 X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

 _search=false&nd=1355782305975&rows=15&page=1&sidx=modified&sord=desc&search=&category=all
```

and, here is the service:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class GridAccess
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
    )]
    public GridResponse Execute()
    {
        var request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
```

All references to `request["fieldName"]` worked before under .NET 4.0 and now, after upgrade to .NET 4.5, they return NULLs.

Answer (score 2):

The issue's root cause looks to be the same as the issue described in post : [Visual Studio 2012 install broke my 2010 WCF project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391586/visual-studio-2012-install-broke-my-2010-wcf-project). I can see your code starts working again if I follow the work around suggested in this post. You can refer to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/praburaj/archive/2012/09/13/accessing-httpcontext-current-request-inputstream-property-in-aspnetcompatibility-mode-throws-exception-this-method-or-property-is-not-supported-after-httprequest-getbufferlessinputstream-has-been-invoked.aspx) blog post for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Please keep us posted on any other bugs with the same root cause, and let us know when you have fixed them.

Comment: I already rolled back to VS 2010 and uninstalled .NET 4.5. Things are back to working with .NET 4.0. At this time, I am abandoning the idea of upgrading to .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0):

To resolve these kind of issues. Just add the System.Web DLL to the Assembly.
Then reference it like this for example:

```
System.Web.HttpRequest request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
```