# This method is not supported after HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream has been invoked

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, iis-7

So in an IHttpModule I am trying to grab a bufferless input stream:

`HttpContext.Current.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream(true);`

But I get this error upon upload of the file I'm trying to send to a controller method:

`This method or property is not supported after HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream has been invoked.`

I have already researched articles similar to these:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/praburaj/2012/09/13/httpcontext-current-request-inputstream-property-throws-exception-this-method-or-property-is-not-supported-after-httprequest-getbufferlessinputstream-has-been-invoked-or-httpcontext-cur/

[How should I use HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635815/how-should-i-use-httprequest-getbufferlessinputstream)

But the add key app setting doesn't seem to make a difference.

Here is my stacktrace:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): This method or property is not supported after HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream has been invoked.]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureFiles() +3678728
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Files() +13
   System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper.get_Files() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.HttpFileCollectionValueProvider.GetHttpPostedFileDictionary(ControllerContext controllerContext) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.HttpFileCollectionValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +69
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider() +30
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +105
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +743
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +465
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__14(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +18
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +374
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +384
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
var a = Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

a.Result returns the byte array which then you can use to convert to something you need.

Comment: I still get the exception using this method.